# Upload PDF to server failed with android studio retrofit

Tags: java, android, pdf, retrofit

I tried to upload a **pdf** file with `Retrofit`, and several times it **failed** because I couldn't read the file path properly. So when checked with `file.exist()` the result is false.

the result is:

```
2021-03-01 19:08:27.145 9017-9017/com.dennyprastiawan.ebaak E/TAG: onActivityResult: false /storage/emulated/0/storage_root/Download/kurikulumbaru9.pdf
```

when I replace the path with a specific path like: `(URLFILE.replace("/storage_root",""))`

Then I display with this path below , The result is a **successful** file upload to the server. However, this becomes a problem when changing devices where the paths are not the same :

```
String URLFILE = data.getData (). GetPath ();

filename.setText (URLFILE);
```

my code to get file pdf:

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
       if(requestCode==9 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
           openFile();
       } else {
           displayExceptionMessage("Anda tidak memiliki permission untuk mengakses storage");
       }
    }
public void openFile(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pilih file"),PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
    }
```

Activity result is:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data != null){
                SString URLFILE = data.getData().getPath();
            fileuri = data.getData();
            File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(fileuri));
                if(fileuri!=null){
//                files = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), URLFILE.replace("/storage_root",""));
                    namaFile.setText(URLFILE);
                    Log.e("TAG", "onActivityResult: "+file.exists()+" "+file.toString() );
                    //String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(fileuri);
                } else {
                    displayExceptionMessage("select file");
                }
}



private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        String result;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Delete `getRealPathFromURI()`. Use a `ContentProvider` to get access to the content identified by the `Uri`. In the duplicate, I point out multiple resources for setting up a `ResponseBody` for uploading content identified by a `Uri`, and you can use that with OkHttp/Retrofit.

Comment: can you give me link for using ContentProvider in actual case.thanks

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I meant `ContentResolver`, not `ContentProvider` there. The duplicate answer has links to [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3585#issuecomment-327319196) and [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html) and [this](https://cketti.de/2020/05/23/content-uris-and-okhttp/) for implementing an `InputStreamRequestBody` that works with a `ContentResolver`.